# Is there a translation for "cougar"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

I mean *cougar* as in a middle-aged woman seeking a romantic relationship with a younger man. I know the term *asaltacunas*, but this applies to both men and women, so I would like to know if there is a term referring only to women.

Comment: For example the TV series "Cougar town" doesn't have a translated title (at least in Spain) probably because of the lack of an accurate term for "cougar" in Spanish.

Comment: Me sorprende que no hayan traducido algo en España. Cuando estuve allá, inclusó vi la película "Spanglish" doblada, joder! :)

Comment: In Peru, cougar can be equivalent to "Chibolera" (Chibolero for a man) it comes from the word "Chibolo" that is loosely translated as "brat". So it means, a Woman interested in younger men.

Answer (score 6):

It’s interesting to notice that even though (at least in Spain) “middle-aged women seeking romantic relationships with younger men” are nowadays a relatively common species, there isn’t a specific word to name those ladies, maybe because the phenomenon is recent.

It’s very strange that a slang word doesn’t exist yet, as it is a familiar character in novels, movies and television.

The English “cougar” doesn’t exist as a common anglicism.

A sexually bold or agressive woman could be called a ***tigresa***, a ***leona*** and a ***loba***, but she could be of any age.

So for now we have to translate “cougar” as ***una mujer madura que persigue hombres jóvenes***.

Comment: +1 por "loba". Me parto.

Comment: Cuatro años después seguimos sin tener un término para esto. Pero dado que "cougar" significa "puma", tus opciones animalescas molan bastante.

Answer (score 2):

*Robacunas* podría ser, pero también haría referencia a otros rangos de edades, por ejemplo un joven de 22 años saliendo con una chica de 16 podría ser calificado de robacunas.

El término que mas se le acerca creo que sería *Comehombres*, ya que por tratarse de alguien que *come* hombres, da la idea de que se trata principalmente de una mujer, y el término hombre también hace un poco referencia a un determinado rango de edades, ya que los muy jovenes quedarían excluídos. Las *cougars* si bien no creo que le hagan asco a nada, tienen un target aproximado que arranca en los veintitantos.

Además, *comehombres* también comparte junto con *cougar*, el sentido de que están al acecho siempre en busca de nuevas "presas".

Comment: No sé si "comehombres" sea muy explícito acerca del rango de edades. Puedes tener una chica de 18 años que sea una "comehombres". Quizás para el 2021 la RAE agregue "cugar" si Cougar Town tiene mucho éxito :P (o una nueva acepción para "puma", jeje). En Perú se dice "rompecunas", aunque "robacunas" y "asaltacunas" se entienden perfectamente.

Comment: Si, es cierto, *comehombres* no hace referencia a la edad de quien porta el nombre. Pero *robacunas* tampoco hace referencia a que se trate de una mujer. Creo que va a tener que arriesgarse a algún tipo de ambigüedad, que tal vez se pueda eliminar por contexto.

Comment: Mi error, me refería a que en Perú se dice "rompecunas" en vez de "robacunas", no a que sea el término correcto para "cougar". Estuve preguntando por el término a varios amigos y ninguno me supo dar respuesta. ¿Será algo cultural? Para hombres el término sería "viejo verde", casi con seguridad. ¿Qué opinas de "vieja verde"?

Comment: Yo diría que es un tema cultural. El estereotipo de *cougar* hace referencia normalmente a una buena posicion económica, y en los países con menor grado de desarrollo no debe ser tan común este tipo de situaciones. No es que no existan, pero probablemente en mucha menor medida, al punto de no existir un término tan específico. *Viejo verde* y otros hacen referencia a esta diferencia de edad, pero hay tantos parámetros en juego que es casi tema para otro post. Respecto a la pregunta original, *cougar*, parecería no tener una traducción exacta. *Vieja verde* aunque se entiende, no me suena.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a [SpanishDict](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/cougar) se usan también los términos `rompecunas` (similar a *asaltacunas* o *robacunas*) y `lagartona`

> Me gusta salir con **lagartonas** porque lo pagan todo.

SpanishDict aclara que este término es un coloquialismo de México.

[Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=cougar) propone (además de *robacunas*) el término `comepibes`. Indica que es un término coloquial, aunque no dice de donde.